# MALFORMED_REQUEST on PayPal execute payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, paypal

I've lost almost two whole days trying to solve PayPal related issues.
I'm trying to execute a payment after user's approval, but I'm getting MALFORMED_REQUEST everytime I send the Curl request.

```
def execute
 # Get the access_token
    token = get_paypal_token(false)
    payer_id = params[:PayerID]
    payment_id = params[:paymentId]
    # Creating the data object
    stringJson = {:payer_id => "#{payer_id}"}

    # You can see that I hard-coded the payer_id to ensure the JSON is correct
    curlString = `curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer #{token}" -H "Content-Type:     application/json" -d '{"payer_id" : "QULQSFESGMCX2"}' https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/#{payment_id}/execute/`
end
```

And the response is:

```
"{\"name\":\"MALFORMED_REQUEST\",\"message\":\"The request JSON is not well formed.\",\"information_link\":\"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST\",\"debug_id\":\"6431589715660\"}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are running it from windows. I tried your command from my windows and my test server receiving the json as `'{payer_id`. It is happening because of your single quote.

I have changed the single quotes into double and it is working fine here with me.

```
-d "{\"payer_id\" : \"QULQSFESGMCX2\"}"
```

You can run the curl command from the console and see what happens, after that you can push it inside your ruby script code.

Comment: Thank you alot! You saved my week. It worked great. If I had rep I'd thumb you up!